My card flickers like its glitching and its not as smooth as its supposed to be
My flipcard animation flickers and glitches when mouse hovers over it and only flips is the mouse is placed at the center of the card. I added a z-index to help it transition smoother, but that did not work. Does anyone know what might be the problem?
I have added the relevant html, 1 of 3 identical flipcards


.thecard {
  position: relative;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  transition: all 0.8s ease;
  border-radius: 2rem;
  padding: 1.5rem;
  text-align: center;
  margin: auto;
}

.thecard:hover {
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
  width: 300px;
  height: 200px;
}

.thefront {
  position: absolute;
  padding: 1.5rem;
  flex: 1;
  background: white;
  border-radius: 2rem;
  border: rgb(53, 53, 53) 0.1rem solid;
  border-color: rgb(163, 163, 163);
  text-align: center;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  overflow: hidden;
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  z-index: 1;
}

.theback {
  position: relative;
  padding: 1.5rem;
  flex: 1;
  background: rgb(7, 155, 155);
  border-radius: 2rem;
  border: rgb(53, 53, 53) 0.1rem solid;
  border-color: rgb(163, 163, 163);
  text-align: center;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  overflow: hidden;
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
  text-align: justify;
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  z-index: 2;
}

.the-maine-card-container {
  padding: 1.5rem;
  flex: 1;
  border-radius: 2rem;
  text-align: center;
  perspective: 1000px;
}
<div class="about-containers_2">
  <div class="the-maine-card-container">
    <div class="thecard">
      <div class="thefront">
        <h1>Computer Networks</h1>
        <div class="article-container">
          <img src="./assets/computer.png" alt="Project1" class="project-img" />
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="theback">
        <h1 class="Sum">Summary</h1>
        <p class="para">The network was design using Cisco Packer<br/> Tracer for a single-story 100 x 50 meters building<br/> that provide wired and Wi-Fi internet access to approximately
          <br/> 40 employees, accommodating up to 160 untrustworthy Wi-Fi devices.
          <br/> Great simulation tool to learn more about Networks.
        </p>
        <div class="btn-container">
          <button class="btn-btn-color-2-projectbtn" onclick="location.href='https://github.com/'">Github</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>




could you please include the relevant HTML for it to work?

Please see [ask]. You need to create a demo with the editor for a simple HTML/CSS question. Also take the [tour].

The most likely cause is that on hover the element moves so it’s no longer being hovered so it moves back so it becomes hovered again, etc etc but can’t be certain without seeing the HTML structure.

I have added the relevent HTML

If the mouse is away from the center of the card, as soon as the card flips mouse is no longer on the card and hover is disabled. Once card returns to normal position, hover is triggered again. This causes the flicker.
Instead of putting :hover on .thecard use it on the parent as the parent is fixed and only the card rotates which guarantees that hover is triggered properly.
.the-maine-card-container is larger than the card here. I've added hover to it just for demonstration purpose. You can add a parent that is exactly the size of the card and add hover to it so that hover triggers exactly at the edge of your card.
Do not change width and height on hover as it will look really weird. I've also added width and height to .thecard instead of .thecard:hover.


.thecard {
  position: relative;
  width: 300px;
  height: 200px;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  transition: all 0.8s ease;
  border-radius: 2rem;
  padding: 1.5rem;
  text-align: center;
  // margin: auto;
}

.the-maine-card-container:hover>.thecard {
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
}

.thefront {
  position: absolute;
  padding: 1.5rem;
  flex: 1;
  background: white;
  border-radius: 2rem;
  border: rgb(53, 53, 53) 0.1rem solid;
  border-color: rgb(163, 163, 163);
  text-align: center;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  overflow: hidden;
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  z-index: 1;
}

.theback {
  position: relative;
  padding: 1.5rem;
  flex: 1;
  background: rgb(7, 155, 155);
  border-radius: 2rem;
  border: rgb(53, 53, 53) 0.1rem solid;
  border-color: rgb(163, 163, 163);
  text-align: center;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  overflow: hidden;
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
  text-align: justify;
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  z-index: 2;
}

.the-maine-card-container {
  padding: 1.5rem;
  flex: 1;
  border-radius: 2rem;
  text-align: center;
  perspective: 1000px;
}
<div class="about-containers_2">
  <div class="the-maine-card-container">
    <div class="thecard">
      <div class="thefront">
        <h1>Computer Networks</h1>
        <div class="article-container">
          <img src="./assets/computer.png" alt="Project1" class="project-img" />
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="theback">
        <h1 class="Sum">Summary</h1>
        <p class="para">The network was design using Cisco Packer<br/> Tracer for a single-story 100 x 50 meters building<br/> that provide wired and Wi-Fi internet access to approximately
          <br/> 40 employees, accommodating up to 160 untrustworthy Wi-Fi devices.
          <br/> Great simulation tool to learn more about Networks.
        </p>
        <div class="btn-container">
          <button class="btn-btn-color-2-projectbtn" onclick="location.href='https://github.com/'">Github</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>



